# Should I have one big redux-form or multiple ones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is there any reason to keep all my form data in one huge form or the better solution is to make multiple smaller ones and then send all their values as one request?

Comment: Please provide more info regarding what you are trying to accomplish. A screenshot of you form or some code would really help in analysing the issue

Comment: Why? This is not an issue. It's more like a philosophical question, about how to handle huge forms with redux-form.

Answer (score 2):

This is too generic of a question to be accurately answered. It depends on your requirements. If you want all your data to be together in one JSON object, there is no reason not to use a single form (i.e. no performance advantages to keeping your forms small). If you want to submit some of the fields separately, then maybe it makes sense to break it up into multiple forms. Like I said, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I had an idea to make multiple small forms (like making a lot of small components instead of huge one) and then handle all of their values by single function, which has another functions to handle all of their values separately and to send them as one JSON object.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to decorate more than one component (form section, we'll call it) with the `reduxForm()` decorator. As long as you set `destroyOnUnmount` to `false`, you can have multiple components all modifying the same form data (json structure) in Redux independently. Just a thought....

Comment: That is exactly what I did, so I thought "Isn't this a better way to handle huge, complex forms?", that's why I am asking people about their opinion on that topic.